# Transmission rate on BeagleBone Black to uSDcard

Tags: sd-card, beagleboneblack, baud-rate

i did a lot of research, and i didn't find anything about the **velocity/baudrate** of the data transmission from the `BeagleBone` Black to the `uSDcard`, i have the microsdcard configured as extra storage(`FAT32`).

I saw in the hardware schematic of the BBB, data the pins that connect to the uSD card are the `SPI`, so i think its a very fast communication, but i want to know how much.

If anyone knows or have done some tests,  please tell me.

Best regards,
David C.

Comment: It would be better to post it on electronics.stackexchange IMO

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> 48MHz is the max RAW frequency of the interface

Answer in:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/beaglebone/Transmission/beaglebone/cchgPAgXPTY/d1g5Tu0KCwAJ